# Problem writing a database query

Tags: python, sql, django

I have two models, `Location` and `Event`, that are linked by ForeignKey on the `Event` model. The models break down as follows:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField('city', max_length=25)
    slug = models.SlugField('slug')

class Event(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    title = models.CharField('title', max_length=75)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField('start_date')
    end_date = models.DateTimeField('end_date')
```

Each location has multiple events that are ordered by `start_date` descending. The query I am trying to make retrieves the next upcoming event for each of the locations.

Ideally I would like to make this in a single query (I don't want to run a query for every location, as this would cause a lot of unnecessary hits to the database). I have tried using Django's ORM, and I've also tried using raw SQL, but I've hit a bit of a roadblock.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I have come up with a potential solution, though I'm not convinced that it's the best method. It works, which should be enough, but I'm curious to see what the best method of doing this would be.

Anyway, the code I've written reads thus:

```
l = Location.objects.select_related()
qs = None

# Concatenate the related event querysets into a new queryset
for e in l:
    if qs is None:
        qs = e.event_set.all()
    else:
        qs = qs | e.event_set.all()

# Order a slice of the queryset by start_date ascending
qs = sorted(qs[:l.count()], key=lambda s: s.start_date)
```

Comment: post your tries code and raw SQL for compare

Comment: @Gary - I haven't got time right now, but this is definitely, definitely possible in Django's ORM - don't drop into raw SQL for this. I'll try and post an answer later if no one's helped you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ideally I would like to make this in a single query (I don't want to run a query for every location, as this would cause a lot of unnecessary hits to the database)."

This is a false assumption.

1) Django's ORM uses a cache.  It may not query the database as often as you think.  Databases have a cache.  The cost of a query may not be what you think, either.

2) You have `select_related`.  The ORM can do the join for you.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4

Just write the simplest possible loop for fetching Locations and Events.  In the very unlikely event that this is the slowest part of your application (and you can **prove** that it's slowest), then add `select_related` and see how much that improves things.

Until you can prove that this specific query is killing your application, move on and don't worry about "hits to the database".

Next event in each location?

```
[ l.event_set.order_by( start_date ).all()[0] for l in Location.objects.select_related().all() ]
```

Or perhaps

```
events = []
for l in Location.objects.select_related().all():
    events.append( l.event_set.order_by( start_date ).all()[0] )
```

And return that to the template to be rendered.

Don't dismiss this until you've benchmarked it and proven that it is the bottleneck in your application.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, (
    select * from event 
    where location=location.id 
    and start_date>NOW() 
    order by start_date asc 
    limit 1
    )
 from location
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at django aggregation[link text](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), so your result will be agragated by location with a condition to filter future/expired events and min(start_time) returns next event time

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following may be useful:

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS V
  WHERE (V.LOCATION, V.START_DATE) IN
    (SELECT E.LOCATION, MIN(E.START_DATE)
       FROM EVENTS E
       WHERE E.START_DATE >= NOW
       GROUP BY E.LOCATION)
```

Share and enjoy.